# pod 'UICircularProgressRing' is not working anymore

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

After 2 months of doing nothing with my App I wanted to make an update with my new macBook but then I was getting 6 error messages from a pod called  `UICircularProgressRing`. I tried fixing it trough removing, updating and reinstalling but didn't change anything. I assume that either my new macBook or a new Xcode-Version could be the root of my problem. Has anybody another idea how to solve this problem?

[all 6 error messages of pod 'UICircularProgressRing'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3g9F.png)

[error message in definition of pod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXaHS.png)

[is an update due?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDt9b.png)

[also not able to convert to swift 4.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFPZB.png)

Comment: If the third party is not ready for Swift 4.2, then don't update your Swift to 4.2. There is compatibility issues.

Comment: Xcode has already saved me from this automatically.

Comment: https://github.com/luispadron/UICircularProgressRing/issues/152 ?

Comment: Thanks that's definetely my problem... But unfortunately the solution (updating to swift 4.2) isn't possible for me cause I need to build successfully with the currently configured Swift version before attempting a migration. I'm very confused :D